# How to specify a certain output if more than one output files are open in spss

Tags: spss

I have 2 output files open. How do I specify to a certain output file when running the syntax in SPSS?

Answer (score 2):

Your output windows have names that you can see in the upper left corner - e.g:
[image]

You can change this name if you want, so

```
output name "MyOutput".
```

[image]

You can activate any open output window using it's name, like this:

```
output activate "ThisOutput".
freq thisVar.
output activate "ThatOutput".
freq ThatVar.
```

Each `freq` command will run in it's designated output window.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. For those who have the same problem as mine, using @eli-k's example, type "Output Activate MyOuput."